# Django form with two submits, won't respond with the file I create

Tags: python, django, kml

EDIT:  Error I see in the web console trying to click the export to KML button:

```
VM211:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success ((index):260)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:5)
```

javascript:

```
 $('form').submit(function(e){
            $.post('/swsite/globe/', $(this).serialize(), function(data){ 

                //this 

                var json = JSON.parse(data);

                var jsonf = JSON.parse(json.data);
                var json2 = JSON.parse('{"foo" : "bar"}')

                console.log(JSON.parse(data).data);
                for(var i=0; i<jsonf.features.length; i++)
                {
                    var entitycesium = new Cesium.Entity();
                    entitycesium.name = jsonf.features[i].properties.name;
                    entitycesium.polygon=new Cesium.PolygonGraphics({
                                hierarchy :  Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([
                                        jsonf.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][0][0],jsonf.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][0][1],
                                        jsonf.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][1][0],jsonf.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][1][1],
                                        jsonf.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][2][0],jsonf.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][2][1],
                                        jsonf.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][3][0],jsonf.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][3][1],
                                        jsonf.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][4][0],jsonf.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][4][1],
                                    ]),
                                outline:true,
                                outLineColor :  Cesium.Color.RED,
                                material : Cesium.Color.GREEN.withAlpha(0.1),
                            });


                    //when sar processor builds out the json add in the deepviewerurl into it too and ready for loading into db.
                    //entitycesium.description= '<a href=\"' + jsonf.features[i].properties.file_name + '\" target="_blank">Full Resolution Viewer</a>';

                    entitycesium.description= '<a href=\"' +  jsonf.features[i].properties.dzi_location + ' \" target="_blank">Full Resolution Viewer</a>' + 
                        '<p> Country code ' + jsonf.features[i].properties.country_code + '</p>' +
                        '<p> Corner coords ' + jsonf.features[i].properties.corner_coords + '</p>' +
                        '<p> Sensor: ' + jsonf.features[i].properties.sensor + '</p>' +
                        '<p> Target: ' + jsonf.features[i].properties.targetName + '</p>' +
                        '<p> Collection Date: ' + jsonf.features[i].properties.collection_date + '</p>';


                    viewer.entities.add(entitycesium);


                    var numpoints=5;
                    for(var np =0; np<numpoints; np++)
                    {

                //        console.log(jsonf.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][np]);

                    }
                  //  console.log("BREAK");

                }
                //I really hate how the getById does nothing
                    var ev= viewer.entities;
                    viewer.flyTo(ev);
                    //jsonf.features[currentFeature].geometry.coordinates[0][0-5][0-2]
                    //console.log(jsonf.features[0].geometry.coordinates);
                    for(var i=0; i<ev.values.length; i++)
                    {

                        $('#entitylist').append('<option value ='+ ev.values[i].id +'> '+  ev.values[i].name + '</option>');

                    }
                //$('.message').html(ev.values[0].id);
                    //$('.message').html(json.data);
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

What I don't care is why would the browser care if what is coming back is supposed to be a file?

So I finally got two submit buttons working, and then I thought i could just copy the right code and put it in the right portion of the action.  My views.py for this action looks like:

```
def globe(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntityGlobeForm(request.POST)

        #two submit butotns
        #hidden_checkbox means they are interacting with the form
        if request.POST.get('hidden_checkbox'):

            #put items on the virtual globe
            if form.is_valid():
                #you are going to have to make a panel and paginate footprints 


                #object_list = ChangeDetectCSV.objects.filter(processing_level='RAW') #AND DATE

                sensor = form.cleaned_data.get('layer') #it is really sensor
                #if sensor is not 
                object_list = CesiumEntity.objects.filter(sensor = sensor)
                jdata= serialize('geojson', object_list,
                    geometry_field='mpoly',
                    fields=('name','file_name', 'id', 'dzi_location', 'country_code', 'corner_coords', 'sensor', 'targetName', 'collection_date'))

            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data': jdata}))
        #the other means they clicked the download option instead
        else:
                # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate KML.
            print 'building kml'
            kml = simplekml.Kml()
            kml.newpoint(name="Kirstenbosch", coords=[(18.432314,-33.988862)])  # lon, lat, optional height
            response = HttpResponse(kml.kml())
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="botanicalgarden.kml"'
            response['Content-Type'] = 'application/kml'
            print 'about to return response: ' + str(response)
            return response

    else:
        form = EntityGlobeForm

    return render_to_response('swsite/sw_nga_globe.html', {'form':form },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I did have some help here for the hacerking on that POST.get (template code here)

```
 <form action="/" method="post" id="form">{% csrf_token %}
               <!--  {{ form.as_table     }} -->
                <table>
                    {% for field in form %}
                    <tr><td><font color="white">{{field}}</font></td></tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
                <!-- input type="submit" name="LoadLayer" value="Load Entities" />
                <input type="submit" name="notloadlayer" value="Export KML" / -->
                <input type="checkbox" name="hidden_checkbox" id="hidden_checkbox" style="display:none"/>
                <input type="button" value="Load Entities" data-action="true"/>
                <input type="button" value="Export KML" data-action="false"/>                
            </form>
```

So the print response is the KML file, but it never comes back tot he browser, nothing happens.  I thought setting the type and disposition tells the browser the right thing.  I had that code of building the KMl in it's own action called via a link, it worked fine, now stuffing it in that other action code below (globe) does not work now?  Browser does nothing and file never pops up to download or even to start google earth like it did (beings it is a KML file)

Comment: what happens if you comment out those print statements?

Comment: I removed them but still doesn't work.  In an odd twist it might be how im handling y the two submit buttons... there is an error in the web console so I am updating my question to show that error, it is strange to me like the response it bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, we can see that your javascript is trying to parse some text as JSON, but failing because it encounters an invalid character, `<`.

Your view code has two branches depnding on whether the `hidden_checkbox` value is in the submitted form.

If `hidden_checkbox` is present, the view returns a response serialised as JSON.

If `hidden_checkbox` is not present, the view returns some kml; as kml is an xml dialect this will be something like `<kml>...</kml>`.

Your javascript is trying to parse the kml as JSON, and failing because KML is not valid JSON. (You can demonstrate this by typing `JSON.parse('<kml></kml>')` into your browser's javascript console - you'll get an error.)

I'd suggest that you have separate event handlers in your javascript, and two separate views in your python, to handle the two submit buttons.

So:

- if the first button is pressed, the javascript event handler for that button submits the POST request, the view returns JSON, the javascript parses the JSON and does whatever it is supposed to do.
- if the second button is pressed, the javascript handler for that button submits the POST request, the view returns the kml, the javascript does not try to parse as JSON and the download should happen automatically if your headers are set correctly.

---

EDIT: Example code.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="/export-kml/">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <!-- Form fields here -->

    <!-- Handle clicking on this button with javascript -->
    <button type="button" value="Load Entities" data-action="/load-entities/">Load</button>

    <!-- Let the browser handle clicks on this button --> 
    <button type="submit" value="Export KML">Export</button>
</form>
```

**Django** **Views**

```
def globe(request):
    """Handles retrieving items to be displayed on the virtual globe."""

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntityGlobeForm(request.POST)

        #put items on the virtual globe
        if form.is_valid():

            #you are going to have to make a panel and paginate footprints 


            #object_list = ChangeDetectCSV.objects.filter(processing_level='RAW') #AND DATE

            sensor = form.cleaned_data.get('layer') #it is really sensor
            #if sensor is not 
            object_list = CesiumEntity.objects.filter(sensor = sensor)
            jdata= serialize('geojson', object_list,
                geometry_field='mpoly',
                fields=('name','file_name', 'id', 'dzi_location', 'country_code', 'corner_coords', 'sensor', 'targetName', 'collection_date'))

            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data': jdata}))

    else:
        form = EntityGlobeForm

    return render_to_response('swsite/sw_nga_globe.html', {'form':form },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def export_kml(request):

    """Handles exporting KML file using information from the form."""

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntityGlobeForm(request.POST)

        # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate KML.
        if form.is_valid():
            print 'building kml'
            kml = simplekml.Kml()
            kml.newpoint(name="Kirstenbosch", coords=[(18.432314,-33.988862)])  # lon, lat, optional height
            response = HttpResponse(kml.kml())
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="botanicalgarden.kml"'
            response['Content-Type'] = 'application/kml'
            print 'about to return response: ' + str(response)
            return response

    else:
        form = EntityGlobeForm

    return render_to_response('swsite/sw_nga_globe.html', {'form':form },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('button[value="Load Entities"]').on('click', function () {
    // Submit the form to the url defined in the button's data-action attribute.
        console.log('Handling Loading Entities');
        var form = $('#form');
        $.ajax({
            type: form.prop('method'),''
            url: $(this).data('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                // Do something with the returned data.
                console.log(data);
            } 
        });
    });

});
```

**Explanation**

I've changed the form so that its **action** attribute points to the view that handles the KML export.  The 'Load Entities' button has been given a 
**data-action** attribute that points to the view that handles returning JSON data (you must change these urls to match your views).  The 'Export KML'
button has had its type changed to **submit**, so that clicking on it will submit the form to the KML export view without requiring any javascript.

Based on the code in your question, I've simplified the `globe` view and added an `export_kml` view to handle exporting the kml.  Now that we are using two
views there is no longer any need for the `hidden_checkbox` logic in the view (or in your javascript).

Your javascript needs to handle clicks on the 'Load Entities' button; the clickhandler that I've written submits the form to `globe` view.

Clicks on the 'Export KML' button are handled by the browser; this way if the form is successfully submitted the KML attachment will be return and automatically
handled by the browser.  Handling attachments in Ajax POST requests is quite tricky, letting the browser handle it is best.

Comment: thank you this totally makes sense now that I rethink about this.  The event handler is capture that kml coming back and its supposed to be parsing json and encounters the kml and dies or something similar.  I have to say, I am not sure how to have two buttons on the same submit form call two different views like your suggestion states.  Also, the event handlers in javascript I have now is on the same form submit.  I worked to get these two buttons on the same form, my hack didnt pay off cause I need the diff handlers.  Not sure how to go about that...

Comment: secondly, does a javascript event handler look any different for a file download ?  I am guessing i want something like $('form').submit(function(e){ and I want a different form submit maybe I can ask it which one in the input button click ?   seeing the hidden data value and if its one , call one form submit and if another call a different one?  This seems messy and like there is a better way to do this?

Comment: @Codejoy I'll add some handler code later today, but one question first.  In your example code, the kml branch of the view doesn't use any fields from the form at all - is this the case in your real code?

Comment: ty so much, and it does use stuff form the form, it will look at what option is selected...and use that to fetch data from DB to create kml

Comment: Thank you this worked, mostly.  Since I am letting the browser handle the export KML I still need data from the form (the layer that its to export)  I have code like this in the load entities, it reads the layer `sensor = form.cleaned_data.get('layer') #it is really sensor`  but if it sees that in the export_kml it throws an error about no cleaned_data in EntityGlobeForm ?  maybe I need to fish this layer out of the request.POST information?

Comment: I think I missed out calling `form.is_valid()` in the `kml_export` view, so there wouldn't be any cleaned data - sorry about that.  I'll amend the answer.

Comment: oh easy fix, I didn't see it wasn't there (heck I didn't realized its what creates that cleaned data)  thanks!  All is good you rock